# Deploying a Computer Vision pipeline using Kubeflow on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, computer-vision, kubeflow

Can I run a computer vision pipeline with Kubeflow? Is it a good idea, would it run efficiently?

Let's say the steps of the pipeline would need to be image segmentation, some filtering and what not (gpu enabled opencv until now) and maybe a tensorflow serving for a CNN at the end.

Any useful resources?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The [kubeflow pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/getting-started-kubeflow-pipelines) would make a good fit with your specific use case.
The idea is that you containerize all the individual steps that you want to have decoupled, something like: 1/ preprocessing, 2/ training, 3/ serving. Each container is designed so it can take the relevant arguments that you want to modify over time to run different versions of the pipeline.

- For the preprocessing image I would suggest to start from a GPU image with opencv installed that drops the output on Google Cloud Storage.
- For the training you could leverage the `google/cloud-sdk:latest` image that comes with gcloud command so you just copy over your code and run the ml engine command.
- For serving, you could use ml engine to deploy the model and thus start building the image from again `google/cloud-sdk:latest`, alternatively you could use the TF serving [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/serving/tags/) that are available off the shelf and you only need to specify the bucket where your saved model is stored and the model name [see instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker).

This [blog posts](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-kubeflow-machine-learning-pipeline-part-1-efea7a4b650f) describes how to build a similar pipeline.